# How to switch idle from 64 bit to 32 bit?

Tags: python-idle

I am running windows 10, latest Python, latest pygame and my system is a 64 bit system.

I have just made a game, and would like to open by double clicking on its file, but I need to open it in 32 bit IDLE, because all my 'plugins' like pygame are 32 bit. By default, IDLE opens in 64 bit.

How do I make it open in 32 bit by default?

Comment: Have you considered writing a `.cmd` file just for the game?

Comment: No, how would i do that? Bearing in mind it uses multiple .py files

Comment: Got it; you need it for editing, not running. Look at your `PATH` environment variable, somewhere in computer properties. (Sorry, I did not touch Windows for a while.)

Comment: Double clicking on a .py script should run py.exe to run the script directly by looking for a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python3.6-32` to run the required version of python.exe. It's not supposed to open it in an editor or development environment such as IDLE. The installed versions of IDLE are set up on the right-click menu. At least that's how it's *intended* to work. But it's your machine to configure how you want.

Comment: Why not right click on the file, select Properties, and change the "opens with" option to point to the 32-bit Python/IDLE?

Comment: Yes, go to properties and change it

Answer (score 2):

### Here are some options:

***A.***  Manually open the 32-bit version of IDLE:

1. Navigate to the appropriate menu entry within the [image: Windows menu] programs menu and open your script with: `File --> Open...`
2. Run it with: `Run --> Run Module (F5)`.

---

***B.***  Manually open the 32-bit version of IDLE via the command line:

1. Click the Windows menu icon: [image: Windows menu]
2. Type:  `CMD`
3. In the terminal, type: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib\idle"` and press `[ENTER]`

---

***C.***  Use [PIP](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) to install the matching (64-bit) wheel for pygame:

1. Click the Windows menu icon: [image: Windows menu]
2. Type:  `CMD`
3. Right-click `Command Prompt`
4. Select `Run as administrator`
5. In the terminal, type: `"C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip" install pygame` *and press `[ENTER]`*

   - [*If you get an error then you should try manually downloading and installing the appropriate package (aka. wheel):*](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)
     `pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

---

If either of the first two options ( A or B ) work for you, then you should be able to utilize the: Right-click `-> Open With -> Choose another app -> More apps -> [x]Always use this app to open .py files -> Look for another app on this PC -> (navigate to the same location as option A. or B.)`

If the third option ( C. ) worked for you, then your respective (64-bit) version of Python/IDLE should now have pygame (64-bit) installed.  So it should work even if the 64-bit version of IDLE is launched.

Otherwise, try what eryksun said about the hashbang line.  Place it ***all alone on the very first line*** of your script:
`#! /usr/bin/env python3-32`

Comment: If one doesn't care about IDLE and just wants to launch a particular version of the Python interpreter on Windows (ie. 32-bit v3.x.x) `py -3-32 \path\to\your_script.py`

Comment: Oh yeah, also (IDLE with latest 32-bit 3.x version installed): `py -3-32 -m idlelib your_script.py`